# Responsive layout, overflow, x-scroll showing

Tags: html, css, overflow

everyone. 
I'm having a problem with responsive layout. On big screen everything looks fine, the problems emerge when I resize the browser. My navigation doesn't stretch in full width, even though Its width is 100%.

html for nav:

```
<header>
    <div class="navigation">
        <h3>lorem<span class="bold">ipsum</span></h3>
        <div class="logo">
            <h3>your<span class="red">logo</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="active close"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="subMenuToggle"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our process</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our people</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Social</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Get in touch</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Hire</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Careers</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subMenu">
        <div class="subNav">
            <ul>
                <li class="active2"><a href="#">WHAT WE DO</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PEOPLE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">VALUES</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And, SCSS:

```
.navigation {
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
background: white;

.nav {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    ul {
        margin: 32 0;


            li {
                display: inline-block;
                margin-right: 30px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-size: 14px; 
                font-weight: bold;
                height: 38px;
                font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
                transition: all 200ms ease-in;

                span {
                    color: gray;

                }

                a {
                    color: inherit;
                    display: inline-block;
                    height: 40px;
                    text-decoration: none;
                }

                &:active {
                    border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(185, 151, 106);
                    color: rgb(185, 151, 106);
                }



            }
                .active {
                    border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(185, 151, 106);
                    color: rgb(185, 151, 106);
                }

    }  
}
```

Also, images are doing the opposite, they go beyond to view port, so you need to scroll in order to see full width. Since all images are done the same way, he's a one example:
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="section1">
            <img src="Assets/img/Header/Header.PNG" alt="header1">
            <div class="contentBox1">
                <p class="kicker2">Sed ut Perspiciatis</p>
                <h2>Nemo Enim</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque lobortis feugiat risus nec scelerisque. Sed sagittis magna quis sodales convallis. In convallis nec lacus sed fermentum. Integer ultrices felis ac quam commodo, a viverra enim condimentum. Praesent gravida magna in aliquet luctus.</p>
                <button type="button" class="cta1">AT VERO EROS</button>
            </div>
            <div class="contentBox2">
                <h2>QUIS AUTEM VEL<br> EUM DOLOR</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque lobortis feugiat risus nec scelerisque. Sed sagittis magna quis sodales convallis.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="ImageBox1">
                <img src="Assets/img/Header/img1.PNG" alt="img1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and CSS:

```
.container {
margin: 0 auto 395px;
width: 1210px;
@include clearfix;

.section1 {
    width: 1210px;
    position: relative;
    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 480px;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    .contentBox1 {
        position: absolute;
        width: 450px;
        height: 543px;
        background: white;
        bottom: -270px;
        left: 65px;
        z-index: 1;


        p.kicker2 {
            margin: 80px 0 0 90px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: $ThemeColor;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        }

        h2 {
            margin: 18px 0 32px 90px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 45px;  
            font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
        }
        p {
            margin: 0 50px 0 90px;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            color: grey;
        }

        .cta1 {
            background: white;
            color: black;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;
            justify-content: center;
            width: 235px;
            height: 60px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            margin: 37px 0 0 90px;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            &:hover {
                cursor: pointer;
                background: rgb(233, 233, 233);
            }
            &:active {
                position: relative;
                top: 1px;
            }
        }

    }
    .contentBox2 {
        position: absolute;
        width: 270px;
        height: 274px;
        background: rgb(40, 40, 40);
        bottom: -270px;
        left: 515px;
        z-index: 1;

        h2 {
            color: $ThemeColor;
            margin: 40px 0 18px 37px;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        }
        p {
            color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
            margin: 0 56px 0 37px;
            font-size: 17px;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        }
    }
    .ImageBox1 {

        img {
        position: absolute;
        width: 180px;
        height: 182px;
        bottom: -270px;
        left: 965px;
        z-index: 6;
        }
    }
}
```

It really drives me crazy. Also, why when I make a media query, for example, for (max-width: 700px), it starts to effect page much sooner, like around 1000px? It's like it's not in sync. This whole responsive layout gives me a headache...
Sorry for a long post...
P.S. 
If you wanna see whole code, here's a gitHub reppo: https://github.com/Vukasin90/test

Answer (score 1):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 770px) {
  body {
    min-width: 770px; }
    body .navigation {
      width: 100vh; /* <----- here*/
      height: 70px;
      background: white; 
}
```

I think this might be an issue. Your navigation width has value in viewheight instead of viewwidth is that intentional?

Comment: It's just something I tried, in order to see where's the problem. 
Now, it's like this:
"@media screen and (max-width: 770px) {
    .navigation {
        width: 768px;
        .nav {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}"
And, the problem still persists. Actually, I have an empty space to my right side of the page.There is no margins jumping, nothing. It's just there, for some reason.I took care of the page element's.It's just that empty body space (and it's not even a body. Body is within the page elements.). It's just empty space,that inherited the background color of body,

Comment: I just figured it out. Even tough, margins didn't jump out, padding did. And, the reason I didn't see is it didn't show. I had ti put cursor precisely on a certain spot, and then it showed. When I reduced the width of those divs, empty space disappeard...